# How to get variable value after . operator..?

Tags: javascript, json

I have Json like

```
var sampleJson=[{
A101:20000
}];
```

while get the value from json in java script

```
var col=A101;
var value=sampleJson[0].col
```

here col variable have value A101

that i need to replace here in below line

```
var value=sampleJson[0].col
```

how to get value after this .operator..?

Comment: `sampleJson[0][col]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
var col = 'A101';
var value=sampleJson[0][col]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string with `A101` and square brackets.

```
var col="A101";
var value=sampleJson[0][col];
```

Comment: Thanks "var value=sampleJson[0][col]" it works